# Group multiple times by day (multi-value date field)

Tags: datetime, theming

So I have a date field that allows multiple values. In this particular case, I have something like:

```
[0] = Monday, 4pm
[1] = Monday, 6pm
[2] = Tuesday, 10am
[3] = Wednesday, 11am
[4] = Wednesday, 3pm
```

At the moment, all I can manage to do is get it to display all fields in whatever format I want, but each one is treated individually like this:

```
Monday, 4pm, Monday, 6pm, Tuesday, 10am, Wednesday, 11am, Wednesday, 3pm
```

What I need to to group them by day so they appear as:

```
Monday, 4pm, 6pm
Tuesday, 10am 
Wednesday, 11am, 3pm
```

I'm currently trying to cobble together a custom theme_field__field-date() function to try and do it because I gave up on views.

Is this the correct way to do it? Is there a shortcut?