# How do you apply timezone formatting to a date?

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm trying to build my own output for a date field *see [Group multiple times by day (multi-value date field)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8345/group-multiple-times-by-day-multi-value-date-field) *, but the problem I'm having is how to apply the timezone?

This article -> [Date value to different date format](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/date-value-to-different-date-format) and nearly every other reference out there tells me that it should be applied by default. But it isn't.

What I'm doing is theming the field with:

```
function theme_field__field_times($vars){
    $dates = $vars["element"]["#values"];
    foreach($dates as $item){ // there are many dates, so we'll cycle through each one
        $date = ('U', strtotime($item['value'])); // convert to unix time
        print('This date renders as: '.format_date('$date', 'custom', 'D d/m/Y - g:ia', '', date_default_timezone_get());
    }
}
```

Which outputs, for example, **27/07/2011 -1:10pm**. The value should be **27/07/2011 - 11:10pm**, or the date that my function spat out +10hours - the timezone ('Australia/NSW') that should have been applied...

date_default_timezone_get() is returning the correct timezone.

If I let Drupal render the dates using it's default field theming, the dates are right.

So why isn't the timezone being applied? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I did something along the lines of this for a date field coming in as UTC that I wanted output using my site's timezone.

```
print format_date(strtotime($row->field_data_field_event_field_event_value.' '.$row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_event['und'][0]['timezone_db']));
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you pass to the function are wrong; in particular, what you pass as last argument should be the one before it.
The arguments the function accepts are `format_date($timestamp, $type = 'medium', $format = '', $timezone = NULL, $langcode = NULL)`, but your fourth argument is an empty string, and then you pass the timezone identifier as last argument, which should be the language identifier.
You are also using `'$date'` as first argument.

Try with the following call:

```
format_date($date, 'custom', 'D d/m/Y - g:ia', date_default_timezone_get()).
```

Comment: Thanks - fixed that but the time is still not being adjusted.

I think, because the site is 'Australia/NSW', and the time as supplied in the 'value' doesn't have a timezone, it's assuming it is already Australia/NSW and not applying any adjustments.

The array the date field returns looks like:
`[value] => 2011-07-27T23:10:00
[timezone] => Australia/NSW
[timezone_db] => UTC
[date_type] => date`

I would assume there's some pre-prepared function in the Date API for doing this, but I can't find it.

Comment: As far as I can see, it works when the server is using the UTC timezone; Drupal core modules normally use just three parameters, and the date is automatically converted basing on the Drupal site settings, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert the time-string to a timestamp using the strtotime function, it already applies the default timezone. Later, when calling format_date, the timezone is applied again - which breaks the calculation.

The solution is to add "UTC" to your time-string, which sets the "neutral" timezone. So you get a timestamp in UTC, which is then formatted and converted to the default timezone by format_date().